# ServiceController in Managed c++? (.NET)

Tags: .net, c++, managed

Hi im trying to start/stop/disable windows services via a .NET app but I cant seem to get the below code to work, it keeps saying that Error    4   error C2065: 'ServiceController' : undeclared identifier

What is the correct reference for this? I cant seem to find the correct one in System::

```
String ^servicename = "srservice";



             // Stop the service if it's started.

             ServiceController^ controller = new ServiceController(servicename);
             if (controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)

                 controller.Stop();



             // Set the startup type of the service.

             String^ serviceregistrylocation = String::Format("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{0}", servicename);

             RegistryKey ^localMachine = Registry::LocalMachine;

             RegistryKey servicekey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(serviceregistrylocation, true);



             // Set value to 2 for automatic, 3 for manual, or 4 for disabled.

             servicekey.SetValue("Start", 3);
```

Ok so i modified the code and it now compiles but throws an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

```
                 String ^servicename = "Fax";



             // Stop the service if it's started.

             ServiceController^ controller = gcnew ServiceController(servicename);
             if (controller->Status == ServiceControllerStatus::Running)

                 controller->Stop();



             // Set the startup type of the service.

             String^ serviceregistrylocation = String::Format("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{0}", servicename);

             RegistryKey ^localMachine = Registry::LocalMachine;

             RegistryKey ^servicekey = localMachine->OpenSubKey(serviceregistrylocation, true);



             // Set value to 2 for automatic, 3 for manual, or 4 for disabled.
             try{
             servicekey->SetValue("Start", 4);
             }
                 catch ( Exception^ e ) 
        {
            MessageBox::Show( e->Message );
        }

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a using statement for `System::ServiceProcess`?  If not you'll have to fully qualify the class with `System::ServiceProcess::ServiceController`.  Also, you have to include a reference to the System.ServiceProcess.dll assembly.  You can add a reference by selecting Properties from the right click context menu on your project.  Then select "Common Properties" from the top of the tree view on the left hand side.  Click the "Add New Reference..." button and select the appropriate reference.  Or you can right click on the project and select "References..."

[image]

Comment: Thats just the issue, I have no System::ServiceProcess::ServiceController it seems, when it try to search for it in System::  the serviceProcess does not show up.

Comment: Hmm now im getting an error saying that :Error 4 error C3673: 'Microsoft::Win32::RegistryKey' : class does not have a copy-constructor

Comment: You forgot the hat^.  And to close your question.

Comment: Can someone tell me what @ does infront of this?

(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{0}", servicename);

I took it out in my code because it did not work but in the tutorial they had it

Comment: @"" is a way of expressing a literal string in C#.  This means that the normal \'s are not used as an escape sequence character.  Without the @ the \n is a new line, \t is a tab, etc.  You have to use \\ to get an actual slash when writing strings.

Comment: Oh i see, but when i try to use @ with the code above I get unknow character 0x40. Would using \\ be the same thing?

Comment: You can't use @ in C++.  You have to use the \\ for every \.